# How do I interrupt threads in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm having a problem with the following code. In my real situation, the logic encapsulated by SomeClass has blocking logic, so I need it to be called with `reactor.callFromThread()`. I want the loop in SomeClass.run() to stop when I issue a sigint signal, and my understanding is that putting some code to do this in the addSystemEvent hook should handle this. I think this might be more a problem with my understanding of Python and threading than with Twisted itself.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import time

class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while(self.running):
            print('foo')
            time.sleep(5)

    def stop(self):
        print('stopping')
        self.running = False

someClassInstance = SomeClass()

def cleanup():
    someClassInstance.stop()

reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', cleanup)
reactor.callFromThread(someClassInstance.run)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to safely and generically interrupt a thread in a programming language like Python.  Java used to have this feature, but [they removed it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) because it is inherently unsafe.  (There is a new feature in Java, `Thread.interrupt`, which is a limited version with fewer problems, but it still complicates the task of writing multithreaded code).

This is why Twisted provides lots of ways to avoid threads.  If you don't need them, don't use them.  For example, instead of calling `time.sleep(n); foo()` just do `reactor.callLater(n, foo)` and you will get the same effect, except that `callLater` returns an object you can use to easily cancel or defer `foo`'s execution if it hasn't happened yet.

If you have an example of what you're *actually* trying to do rather than substituting "`time.sleep`" for "and then something happens", please open another question expounding on it.  The answer really depends on *what* you are doing - are you actually waiting on time? Blocking on I/O to another process? Another machine?  Twisted has appropriate facilities for all of these.

Comment: Essentially, I'm making blocking network calls: calling some legacy libraries that do synchronous IMAP client work. For the moment I have this at least working by using `callInThread()` instead of `callFromThread()`, but I'd love to know how I can sandbox my blocking code in a more correct Twisted way. Edit: I just realised I can do this with `deferToThread()`, which seems nicer, but I'm still using threads!